# Print information from fql\sql table

Tags: python

I'm new to python, this is currently printing correctly, though I want it to show a specific number from the print.

```
from facepy import GraphAPI

graph = GraphAPI("Facebook access token")
query = graph.fql('SELECT unread_count FROM mailbox_folder WHERE folder_id = 0')
print query
```

This prints out

```
{u'data': [{u'unread_count': 2}]}
```

though I'd like to only show the number 2.. I've tried countless methods which I've deleted them as I tried. 
Why does python prints with the u' behind the information being printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query` is a dictionary of a list of dictionaries.

```
>>> k = {u'data': [{u'unread_count': 2}]}
>>> k['data'][0]['unread_count']
2
```

**dictionary** is `{'key': value}`  where key must be a string but value could be anything, from integer to an image. Any valid Python object.

**list** is enclosed with `[]` and its elements are comma separated value. For example:

```
lst_ints = [1,2,3,4]
lst_strs = ['1','2']
lst_dict = [ {'key1': val1}, {'key1': val1} ]
```

In most programming language, to access a list and array you can start with index 0. SO `lst_ints[0]` will be the integer 1.

`query` has a key called `data` so we first access that. Then we see a list and there is one element and the index is 0. Finally, the list contains the key `unread_count`.

`u` just means unicode string.

Comment: That is perfect, I appreciate it very much for the help! Thank you @CppLearner